# Trying CrudRepository - H2 - TableNotFound

Tags: spring, maven, jpa, h2

Below, my configs

Pom.xml

```
`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
 </dependency>`
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class SendSmsController {

    @Autowired
    private DataBaseService dataBaseService;
    @Autowired
    private SendSmsService sendSmsService;

    @RequestMapping(value="/sendSms", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<Sms> sendSms(@RequestBody Sms sms,@RequestParam(required=false) String expirationDate) {

        if(sms.getBody().length() > 160){
            return new ResponseEntity<Sms>(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
        }

        dataBaseService.saveSms(sms);

        return sendSmsService.sendRequest(sms);
    }
}
```

DataBaseService

```
@Data
@Service
public class DataBaseService {

    @Autowired
    private SmsRepository smsRepository;

    public void saveSms(Sms sms) {
        //I try smsRepository.save(sms) too
        smsRepository.save(new Sms(sms.getTo(),sms.getTo(),sms.getBody()));
    }
}
```

SmsRepository

```
public interface SmsRepository extends CrudRepository<Sms, Long> {

}
```

Sms Class

```
@Data
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Sms {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @JsonProperty
    private String from;
    @JsonProperty
    private String to;
    @JsonProperty
    private String body;

    public Sms(String from, String to, String body){
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.body = body;
    };

    public Sms(){
    }

}
```

Config

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public SendSmsService sendSmsService(){
        return new SendSmsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public DataBaseService dataBaseService(){
        return new DataBaseService();
    }
```

This issue occurs when the code reaches "smsRepository.save(sms)". I follow this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ but i think i missing configs. Thank you for any help!

The error again: `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [insert into sms (id, body, from, to) values (null, ?, ?, ?)]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement`

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Table "SMS" not found; SQL statement:
insert into sms (id, body, from, to) values (null, ?, ?, ?) [42102-187]
```

Comment: can you add spring config xml in your question ?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was in my class.

After this work

```
public class Sms {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="fromNumber")
    private String from;
    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="toNumber")
    private String to;
    @JsonProperty
    @Column(name="bodyMessage")
    private String body;
```